# output of the most important and frequently encountered logs

Tags: logging, lan, rsyslog, log-analysis

I have rsyslog + loganalyzer, it simply displays events that are sent by devices on the network. Is it possible to make the most popular events for the day displayed and not disappear?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Is the question simply "is it possible"? Then the answer is yes, it's possible.

Comment: If it is possible, what is needed for this? Help, please, I'm new, I'm trying to figure out what I should study in order to implement this?

Comment: As an example, you could read and count the logs, then sort them by count and *display* the most frequent ones. For future questions, please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) For more tips, see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)